# Visio 2010 and SQL 2012 - Reverse Enginnering

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2012, visio

We have upgraded to SQL 2012 and Am trying to reverse engineer our Dbs into Visio 2010.  I setup a connecting using SQL 11 driver and Visio complains that that driver is not supported.

Any one run into this?

Comment: Here is another [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/d0f934a4-96a4-471d-9985-e92d70984aae/) with a similar question. Since SQL Server 2012 came out after Visio 2010 it is not supported, even though it uses the Native Client.

Comment: Funny, ironic and sad (some things never change, do they): https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/365757/sql-server-2008-driver-for-visio-2007

Answer (score 13):

The Generic OleDB Driver also works for reverse engineering a SQL Server 2012 database using Visio 2010.

(Might not be "supported", but this works).  Select the Generic OLE DB Provider from the list of Installed Visio drivers and click **Next**.  Then pick the Microsoft OLD DB Provider for SQL Server and then go to the **Connection** tab.

1. Enter in your server name,
2. choose the authentication method,
3. Select the database name from dropdown (or build from file) and click the **Test Connection** button.

I didn't need to do anything with the **Advanced** or **All** tabs after the connection succeeded, just clicked **OK** and was able to pick the object types and list of objects and it exported everything to the diagram.

Comment: That's an interesting workaround and an approach that works.

Comment: Can you give any more details on how to go about that? (hint: it'll give you a fair number more rep ;-) )

Comment: Pretty crappy answer considering you didn't indicate how to get this driver. Vote down.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot test it from here, but I would try using the SQL 10 driver if you can.  They usually have high level of compatibility across versions.

Or else try using the Generic ODBC driver.  That almost always works, though you don't always get as much with it.

Comment: I have had luck with the ODBC drivers before as well.. however you don't get access to some of the Binary data types such as XML, Geography etc

Comment: Tried SQL 10.0 and SQL 6.0, neither worked. Although I could setup new ODBC DSN's, they wouldn't show in the ODBC Generic Driver list in the Visio 2010 Reverse Engineer wizard but does under  IBMDB2, Access and Oracle. Using them then warns you that mismatching drivers is not a good idea!

OLE DB was the only one I could get working reliably.

I think a quality control is lacking somewhat around this wizard.

Comment: @MrMcGoo Completely agree.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is "Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server® - Windows" which can be downloaded from:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434